# How to prevent leak memory when close a chrome popup window created by window.open()

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, popupwindow

On chrome newest version, I open my website:

1. I create a popup window by `window.open()` function, this window take a large memory with my business in parent tab. (When open chrome popup window it wasn't create a new chrome object like normal chrome tab, it share with parent).
2. I close this popup window, the memory it take in parent wasn't release.
   Repeat step 1 and 2 the memory still increase and increase.

When I redirect the popup to a blank page as '`chrome://newtab`', the memory it take was release totally.

I want all memory take by popup window was release totally.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are having issues with a new process being read each time you open a window, which is memory intensive. 

This is designed by Chrome: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/threading_and_tasks.md

Therefore I don't believe it can be changed as it brings some advantages, such as isolation of processes (if one window shuts down, it doesn't affect the other).

Comment: @jburtondev, Thanks for your help, but I just need to clear memory when close a window, the page opened on the window is a normal page, it can be run dependence.

Comment: I had the same issue. `window.open`, when used without `"noopener"`, makes a window that will not release memory when it's closed.